# Null check still throws Flow error

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

What is the rule for where you need to put your null check to avoid Flow errors? This code surprised me by giving an error:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";

type Props = {|
  apples: ?Array<Array<string>>,
  oranges: ?Array<Array<string>>,
|};

class FruitBasket extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    if (this.props.oranges == null || this.props.apples == null) {
      return null;
    }

    var dummyVariable = 16;

    var apples = this.props.apples.map((ask) => {
      return null;
    })

    var oranges = this.props.oranges.map((bid) => {
      return null;
    })

    return null;
  }
}

export default FruitBasket;
```

The error is: 
`Cannot call this.props.oranges.map because property map is missing in null or undefined [1].`

It seems silly that the Flow compiler would "forget" the null check after the `var apples = ...` declaration.

Comment: Should you be returning nulls, may be question marks not in “all” the right places.. May be this doc helps https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an validation/ordering issue. Flow doesn't know what `this.props.apples.map()` does, so it is technically possible that it could end up setting `this.props.oranges = null`. Since that could happen, by the time `this.props.oranges.map()` is called, the `if (this.props.oranges == null)` refinement is no longer in effect, and `this.props.oranges` *could* be null, from the standpoint of the typechecker. You have two solutions:

- Move the `if (this.props.oranges == null) return null;` check to just before the `this.props.oranges.map()` call. The downside being that then you split up your bail-out logic, and end up mapping `apples` for no reason.
- Assign the values to temporary variables, so that Flow can tell that their type won't change later. This would be my recommendation.

  ```
  render() {
    if (this.props.oranges == null || this.props.apples == null) {
      return null;
    }
    const { oranges, apples } = this.props;

    var dummyVariable = 16;

    var applesItems = apples.map((ask) => {
      return null;
    })
    var orangesItems = oranges.map((bid) => {
      return null;
    })

    return null;
  }
  ```